# How do I escape string literals using regex for my lexer?

Tags: regex, lexer

Right now, I'm writing a lexer, and I want to be able to match a string token while taking into account escape characters.

So, I wish to be able to parse things like this:

- `'Hello World'` as `[', Hello World, ']`,
- `'There\'s an apostrophe in here'` as `[', There's an apostrophe in here, ']`
- `'This is a backslash: \\'` as `[', This is a backslash: \, ']`.

Currently, I have the following regex rule for matching strings: `/^\s*(')(.*?)(')/s`. `^\s*` accounts for leading whitespace, while `(')(.*?)(')` matches the string 3 times: an opening token, the string itself, and finally a closing token. Once I've recognised a token, I push the matched tokens into an array, and delete the full match from the beginning of the data I'm working with.

I've tried to modify my rule to account for escaped characters, but I haven't been able to make it work, and to be frank, I don't really know where to go from here. I'm at a loss for what to even try. If I check for a backslash, it won't work for two. If I check for two, it won't work for three, etc.

Could someone put me on the right track for how to implement this? This aside, my lexer is already finished and does what it have to do. This is the only thing that remains.

Comment: It seems [`/^\s*(')([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)(')/s`](https://regex101.com/r/qybAVE/2) should work for you.

Comment: @Wiktor So it does. If you submit that as an answer I'll select it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^\s*(')([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)(')/s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qybAVE/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(')` - Capturing group #1: a `'` char
- `([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)` - Capturing group #2:

  - `[^'\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `'`  and `\`
  - `(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of:

    - `\\.` - a `\` followed with any char
    - `[^'\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `'`  and `\`
- `(')` - Capturing group #3: a `'`.